# Sending email notifications from users computer

Tags: c#, winforms, email, notifications

I'm using a gmail account to send email notifications from the app, 
but the problem appears when my customers start using this app. Gmail is blocking login attempts at my customer's locations and notify me about suspicious login attempts.

What is the best practice to send email notification from the app from different locations? I would like to keep the same sender email address.

Comment: You don't need tags in titles. The tag system takes care of that. You can read about it at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. Also, the [general feeling for salutations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/147072) are to not include them. You can add all that to your about page though, linked to by your character sheet at the bottom of each question and answer you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your notice to a web service and have that send you an e-mail.  Relying on user's email systems to be configured properly will lead to disappointment.